# Hide all rows but one/Show rest rows on double click at table row

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to use show/hide mechanic on html table rows. When I doubleclick table row it has `detail` class added and rest of table rows are hidden.

Here's code:

```
<table class='container'>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>ID1</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id='7305' class='testtr'>
        <td>7305</td>
        <td>7305</td>
        <td>Title1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='7381' class='testtr'>
        <td>7381</td>
        <td>7381</td>
        <td>Title2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='8573' class='testtr'>
        <td>8573</td>
        <td>8573</td>
        <td>Title3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

First step works, but I can't fix second step by myself. Did this:

```
<script>
     $(function () {
        $("table").colResizable({ liveDrag: true });
     });

     $('.testtr').dblclick(function () {
       $('.testtr').hide();
       $('.testtr').not(this).addClass('hidden');
       $(this).show();
     });
     $('.testr.detail').dblclick(function () {
       $('hidden').toggle();
       $(this).removeClass('detail');
     });
</script>
```

Like I said, I can hide all rows but one... but I can't unhide hidden rows. Can you help ?

Comment: `.testr.detail` - is it a typo? Also, it won't work, since `.testtr.detail` doesn't exist when the script is executed (I presume it's executed on page load). Use something like `$(document).on('dblclick', '.testtr.detail', function(){...})`

Comment: Use `$('.hidden').toggle();` instead of `$('hidden').toggle();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use toggleClass .Check this sample

```js
    $(function () {
      //  $("table").colResizable({ liveDrag: true });
     });

     $('.testtr').dblclick(function () { 
      //  $('.testtr').hide();
        $('.testtr').not(this).toggleClass('hidden');
        $(this).toggleClass('detail');
       //$(this).show();
     });
   /*  $('.testr.detail').dblclick(function () {
       $('hidden').toggle();
       $(this).removeClass('detail');
     });*/
```

```css
.hidden{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='container'>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>ID1</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id='7305' class='testtr'>
        <td>7305</td>
        <td>7305</td>
        <td>Title1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='7381' class='testtr'>
        <td>7381</td>
        <td>7381</td>
        <td>Title2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='8573' class='testtr'>
        <td>8573</td>
        <td>8573</td>
        <td>Title3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the selector for hidden in your last function should be ".hidden" instead?

Seems like you forgot the dot. Also, the class you added is hidden instead of details as you mentioned, maybe it's also the problem.